# How can I keep a user logged in with java/sqllite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using android studio to create an app. At the moment, users have to log back in everytime they re-open the app. How can I fix this?

```java
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "users.db", null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table users(USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY,PASSWORD TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insert(String username, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long ins = db.insert("users", null, contentValues);
        if(ins == -1) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public Boolean check_username(String username){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", new String[]{username});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public Boolean usernamepassword(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Please note: it is a local server, I'm not entirely sure if this matters - it just means that you can't access one's account from another device. It is not a problem at the moment.

Comment: why not simply use SharedPreferences, sqlite is a bit much for this don't you think?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, but one pattern you can follow is to use a JWT token which your Android app would store into shared preferences.  JWT is one good option for long life sessions, which might free the user from having to login each time he opens the app.

Comment: Yeah, i know about SharedPrefs but I will use a server in the future, so I would like to know how to save things now, so I don't have to re-do everything in the future..

Comment: If you don't want to use SharedPrefs then use Room Persistence Library
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room  instead   of raw SQL queries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900405/simple-username-password-code-in-android-not-working

Also take look at this question, you just need to replace "cake" with string that you get form databse for user and "robot" with string you get from database for pw.